# GPUImage blend two images with mask image

Tags: gpuimage

I'm looking to blend two images together using a third masking (black and white) image.

Just like you would do in Photoshop by having two layers and add a mask on the top one, where the mask is white you see the top layer, where it is black you create transparency so the lower layer is visible. Do I need to create a filter with 3 inputs or can I add the black and white image to one of my two images as an alpha?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried using a GPUImageMaskFilter, then following that with a GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter?

Comment: Hi Brad, I'm doing this with the android variant of the ios lib https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage. I tried the GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter  but it doesn't seem to have the GPUImageMaskFilter yet.

Comment: Hi again, I added the suggested GPUImageMaskFilter to the android-gpuimage library and with GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter chained after it it does exactly what I want! Thanks Brad for the suggestion :)

Comment: Hi joplaete,  i am also facing same problem, can you please tell me the process how do you resolve this issue? i tried GpuImageAlphaBlendFilter but i'm failed to chain multiple filters.

Comment: Hi @joplaete, can you please provide an example? Thanks